# Notification FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE not working on 2.1

Tags: android

I'm  trying to create a notification when an alarm fires. No problem so far.
A notification is shown. The problem is on my device (2.1 Update 1) it is displayed as an ongoing notification. While on another device (2.2) it is working fine and is actually shown as a one time only notification. Has anyone experienced this behaviour, and more important has anyone been able to fix it. It seems like 2.1 is not respecting the  `FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE` or any flags for that mather. See my code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class AlarmHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationManager nm;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Debug.log("Alarm notification received");

    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = intent.getStringExtra("AlarmType");
    CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra("AlarmType");

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Splashscreen.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent.getIntExtra("RequestCode", 0),
            newIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Debug.log("flags: "+notif.flags);
    Debug.log("Defaults: "+notif.flags);

    nm.notify(intent.getIntExtra("RequestCode", 0), notif);
}

}
```

Comment: I executed the same code on both 2.1 update and 2.2, it works as same in both. Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE means that you can clear the same with clear button But you can't clear the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT notification

Comment: So how to clear the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT then. Because I think that is not necessary. And the debug shows me the value of both defaults and flags is 24. The value for FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE and FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL or-ed into notif.flags. So the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT should not be set right ?

Comment: I have provided values and definition as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below values and definition for each one. Hope you can get idea from this.

1. FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE = 8 
   Definition : It should be set if you want the sound and/or vibration play each time the notification is sent, even if it has not been canceled before that.
2. FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT = 2 
   Definition: It should be set if this notification is in reference to something that is ongoing, like a phone call. It should not be set if this notification is in reference to something that happened at a particular point in time, like a missed phone call.
3. FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL = 16 
   Definition: The notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user

Also you if you want to cancel the notification manually then use below code

```
  nm.cancel(id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got that already from the documentation. The problem is that `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` is not set but the notification is still shown as a Ongoing Notification in stead of just a message. I would just like to see a message notification. Eg. The gmail app gives such a message when a message has arrived.

Comment: No I can't. On the other phone however (the one that has 2.2) the notification can be cleared (by the clear button in your notification centre) and is cleared automatic when tapping the notification itself. (Due to the `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

Comment: But I used the same code and it it is working on emulator 2.1

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tried it on an emulator running android 2.1-1 Google API's and it is working as it should. Maybe it is a device specific issue then. (HTC Hero in this case). I suppose I just have to figure out something else for this specific phone. Thank you for your help.